Run amazon/dynamodb-local for use in CDK bundling
I am using CDK bundling on Docker to build a Java package that uses DynamoDB local in its tests.
this.function = new lambda.Function(this, "Function", {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.JAVA_21,
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(`../assets-java/${props.serviceName}`, {
        bundling: {
            command: [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                `mvn clean install && cp /asset-input/target/${props.serviceName}-1.0.jar /asset-output/`,
            ],
            image: lambda.Runtime.JAVA_21.bundlingImage,
            bundlingFileAccess: cdk.BundlingFileAccess.VOLUME_COPY,
            user: "root",
            outputType: cdk.BundlingOutput.ARCHIVED,
            network: "java-build-local",
            volumes: [
                {
                    hostPath: process.env["HOME"] + "/.m2/",
                    containerPath: "/root/.m2/"
                },
                {
                    hostPath: "/var/run/docker.sock",
                    containerPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
                }
            ],
        }
    }),
    handler: props.handler,
    logRetention: RetentionDays.THREE_MONTHS,
    timeout: Duration.minutes(5),
    environment: {
        ...props.env,
        "JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS": "-Dlog4j.configurationFile=log4j2.xml"
    }
})

I've tried running the dynamodb-local container from from the maven build via docker
<plugin>
<groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
<artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.38.0</version>
<executions>
  <execution>
    <id>start-docker-container</id>
    <phase>generate-test-resources</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>start</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
  <execution>
    <id>stop-docker-container</id>
    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
    <goals>
      <goal>stop</goal>
    </goals>
  </execution>
</executions>
<configuration>
  <images>
    <image>
      <name>amazon/dynamodb-local</name>
      <run>
        <ports>
          <port>8123:8000</port>
        </ports>
        <network>
          <name>java-build-local</name>
          <alias>dynamodb-local</alias>
      </network>
      </run>
    </image>
  </images>
</configuration>
</plugin>

And this is telling me that the network is not found
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal io.fabric8:docker-maven-plugin:0.38.0:start (start-docker-container) on project <project>: I/O Error: Unable to start container id [ad35df5ed9e1] : {"message":"network java-build-local not found"} (Not Found: 404) -> [Help 1]

I'd really rather not have to manually create the network ahead of time, so I'm hoping there's a better way to get the dynamodb/local container running alongside the actual bundling container.

The error tells docker is unable to find a network named java-build-local Use this command docker network create java-build-local  to create network manually or use maven configuration.

And how is that done as part of CDK? I don't want to have to run manual commands on what is otherwise a fully automated build, as noted in the original question.
